# How to remove splashscreen in buildbox

Tags: screen, splash-screen

I'm using buildbox 30 days challenge.

I have made a game using this platform. I wanted to ask how to remove the splash screen with the loading bar in buildbox. I replaced the image in the exported png with my own png taking the same dimension and everything. When i try to export it and compile it into eclipse. The app doesn't start. It's get stuck in the start?

Here's the splashscreen by default. The loading bar also disappear when i try to export it into apk.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is the splash screen for the trial version of Buildbox.  The only way to remove this is to purchase the full version.  In fact, this is the only difference between the trial and the full version (besides the trial only working for 30 days).

Comment: It is awesome that you're answering questions regarding your product here on Stack Overflow, but please be aware that signatures and tag lines are usually removed from posts. You can change your user profile to show your name and company affiliation.